APT Errors after broken driver install
I am getting this error when trying to upgrade. this happened after attempting to install USB Bluetooth stick i learned later is unsupported. I also had to remove an invedia driver befor rebooting:
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-36-generic (6.8.0-36.36) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.8.0-36-generic (6.8.0-36.36) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-36-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=6.8.0-36-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for btusb: 4.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-36-generic/x86_64 failed for btusb(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-36-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.8.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.8.0-36-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

The contents of /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/make.log:
$ cat /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/make.log
DKMS make.log for btusb-4.1 for kernel 6.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Sat Jun 29 01:23:07 PM UTC 2024
make -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-36-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-36-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
  You are using:           gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/btusb.o
/var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/btusb.c: In function ‘btusb_probe’:
/var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/btusb.c:3951:13: error: ‘struct hci_dev’ has no member named ‘prevent_wake’
 3951 |         hdev->prevent_wake = btusb_prevent_wake;
      |             ^~
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build/btusb.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-36-generic/Makefile:1926: /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.1/build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-36-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2

How can I solve this issue and remove the broken packages ?
Edit:
I made a mistake atempting to install this driver:  https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.15.git
I was attempting to follow the instructions to install a BT driver found here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2377815#p2377815
I hope someone can help me undo my mistake

Where did this code come from?

binary package for btusb: 4.1 not found Is that related to your USB stick problem?

Other then your title there is nothing in the question about an upgrade or what it is your are upgrading from or to. Please edit the question and add the details.

@David He is likely using source code from my github but for the wrong kernel version

@jeremy31 thank you for your answer. You are absolutely correct and i added the information to the post. As i said i abandoned the device and i am trying to solve the error by taking things back.

I solved it by running dkms status to see the cause of the issue btusb/4.1 and run running dkms remove btusb/4.1. The error has disapeared and the problem is solved. Thanks to @Jeremy31 for reminding my to trace my steps back to undo them.
